# Run Wpf app in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8.1, windows-10

I developed a WPF App and generated a Setup project with visual studio install project. The plataform that I use to developed it was Win 8.1. Now I need to install it on Windows 10, but the application does not run. When I try to execute it quickly I see on windows task manager my app running on second plan and it close quickly. Dot net 3.5 is installed and 4.5. Whats is wrong?

Comment: Did you look through the application events log and see if there is an error that pops up? Try adding logging to the application? There is not enough information here to solve your problem.

Comment: @RonBeyer Simply nothing happing when I try to execute the app. I will try to add a logging

Comment: I understand that, but have you looked through the application events log to see if there is an error that is being logged? The event logs are there to help diagnose these kinds of things...

Comment: have you made sure any custom library references are set to include in your application files, I had a problem like that.  But I agree with @RonBeyer, you need to check the event logs for a starting point.

Comment: @RonBeyer Now I have the Log. How can I show it to you?

Comment: `HResult:    -2146233087` Message: `The invocation of the constructor in kind ' Project.MainWindow ' corresponding to the specified membership restrictions began an exception. ' Line number ' 3' and line position '9' .
Source: PresentationFramework`